# Why the database inserts the same information for 2 lines each time?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

in android studio, I want to insert the data into the SQliteDatabase for one line each time. But  there is a problem for my database that each time I add the information, the information store for 2 line.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Please, post your code as text inside the question, not as an image.

Comment: Also, you're doing that `insert` twice, of course it's going to be inserted twice. Just remove the first `db.insert`

Comment: remove the (first) `db.insert()` line

Comment: just use 
`long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);`
will produce the same result. as 
db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)

Answer (score 1):

You have used `db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues)` twice. Remove the first one.